# Nextjs 12: why activation experimental react concurrent features will disable API routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I recently installed Nextjs v12. I created some Api routes (for example "/api/products"). these routes work correctly, but when I make `concurrentFeatures: true` in `next.config.ts`, Api routes don't work. the displayed error in console is `error - Error: Cannot find module for page: /api/products`

here is my `next.config.ts` file content:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    concurrentFeatures: true
  }
}
```

here are my directories:

```
pages
----api
--------products
------------index.ts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched nextjs issues in github and found this issue:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30586

this issue is already open and labeled as a bug. so this is a bug of nextjs and probably will be fixed in the future.

`-- UPDATE --`

now the https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30586
issue is closed. in nextjs v12.0.4-canary.3 and higher, this problem is fixed

Comment: Hi Reza, This is great